# On Selenium WebDriver how to get Text from div with Mark Tag

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

On Selenium Webdriver, how I can retrieve entire text from div with Mark Tag?

I need to verify that the word 'correctly' is present.

Example HTML code:

```
<div class="faq-node-body">
blah blah blah cor<mark>rec</mark>tly blah blah blah
</div>
```

I manage to verify the 'rec' inside the mark tag
(I use java)

```
webElement  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='faq-node-body' and contains(text(), 'cor')]//mark[contains(text(),rec)]"));
```

But my webElement is only 'rec'.
Does anybody know how to check that the entire word 'correctly' is present with a mark tag on the 'rec' part of the word?

Comment: You have to extract _`cor`_ and _`tly`_ from the text node and _`rec`_ from the `<mark>` node.

Comment: well yes, that's my problem actually. I can get the text `cor`, the text `tly`, and the `rec` from the `<mark>` node, but how do I check that these three elements are 1. in the same div, and 2. follow one another? I have tried to get the entire text from the div, which worked, but that text doesn't contain the `mark` tag, it's only inner text.

Comment: _but how do I check that these three elements are 1. in the same div, and 2. follow one another_: That's reverse engineering. Selenium helps you to identify elements based on tags like `<div>` where as you are asking th reverse :) What is your Testcase all about?

Comment: I need to test a search functionality. When I search a word, or part of a word, the result page shows different divs that contains the searched text, and this text is highlighted with the `mark` tag. So I need to check that not only the word is found, but also that it is highlighted. I can do that just fine, but I was trying to check if, in case of a part of word search, I can find the parts not highlighted and the highlighted part => I can find `<mark>correctly</mark>`, and `<mark>rec</mark>`, but I wanted to check if I could find `cor<mark>rec</mark>tly`.

Comment: Is your test aim to print `cor<mark>rec</mark>tly`?

Comment: yes, exactly what I'm trying to do. I tried to do that by xpath, but haven't succeeded to find the right way to write it I guess because the test always fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **innerHTML** attribute.

```
String innerHTML = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='faq-node-body']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

This will have complete HTML text inside this locator. From there you can validate your data.